# Multiple features in LSTM

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, keras, lstm, rnn

It's clear how LSTM works with 1 feature. But what happens if the number of features is > 1?

[image]

According to the answer proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43723337/multi-dimensional-input-for-lstm-in-keras),

> Keras creates a computational graph that executes the sequence in your bottom picture per feature (but for all units). That means the state value C is always a scalar, one per unit.

But if it executed the process per feature, the result would be `number of units x number of features`. Instead, we get only the number of units (if `return_sequences=False`; otherwise, `number of timesteps x number of units`).

What happens to features and how are they processed? At which step and how are they merged?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case where there are multiple features, the LSTM processes each feature independently, with its own set of weights and biases. The LSTM uses the same computational graph for each feature, but with different parameters (i.e. weights and biases) for each feature.

At each timestep, the LSTM takes in the current values of all features as input, processes them individually using the same computational graph, and produces a hidden state for each feature. The hidden states for all the features at a given timestep are then concatenated and used as input for the next timestep.

In this way, the LSTM is able to capture the relationships between different features across time. The final output of the LSTM will have the same dimensions as the hidden states (i.e. number of units), but will incorporate information from all the input features.